# Is it possible to run sql query against an oracle package?

Tags: sql, oracle, package

I have a query regarding a sql query that passes some data to an Oracle package. My sql query tries to cross against the data that is processed by this package, furthermore I visually validated that this package exists and I have access. But when executing the query, it returns me that there is no such package.

I leave the sql statement:

```
SELECT NVL(ROUND(SUM(MONTO_CUOTA *
                     DECODE(A.TIPO_IMPUTACION, 1, 1, 2, -1, 1) *
                     CONTROL_OPERAC.PCK_SERVICIO.OBTENER_VALOR_1(FECHA_VALOR_CUOTA,
                                                                     TIPO_FONDO) / CASE
                       WHEN VINU_TIPO_MONEDA = 1 THEN
                        1 
                       WHEN VINU_TIPO_MONEDA = 2 THEN
                        CONTROL_OPERAC.PCK_SERVICIO.OBTENER_VALOR_2(FECHA_IMPUTACION)
                       ELSE
                        1
                     END),
                 2),
           0)  
  FROM TABLE(MOVIMIENTO.PCK_CART_PIPELINED.EXAMPLE(44682158,
                                                      1,
                                                      1,
                                                      NULL,
                                                      NULL,
                                                      NULL,
                                                      13-05-1981, 
                                                      31-07-2020, 
                                                      NULL)) A,
       DATOSEXAM.MAPEO_CODIGOS B
 WHERE A.ID_CODIGO_MVTO = B.ID_CODIGO_MVTO
   AND B.TIPO_CUENTA = A.TIPO_CUENTA
   AND B.CLASIFICACION = 'EXAMPLE'
   AND A.ID_ADMINISTRADORA = 900;
```

The error message that I get is the following:

```
ORA-00904: "MOVIMIENTO"."PCK_CART_PIPELINED"."EXAMPLE": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 15, columna: 18
```

Is it possible to execute this query when being against a package?

Thank you very much in advance, I will be attentive to your answers.

Regards!

Comment: It appears that the user that is trying to run the SQL statement has not been granted EXECUTE permissions on the package in which the pipelined table function is defined.  How did you validate that you had access?

Comment: hi @JustinCave thank you very much for your support. The validation was done through the SQL Developer browser, with my user I can see the package and its content. With that the permission is correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The permission to see the code is different from the permission to execute it.  You may be able to read code you can't execute or execute code you can't read.  You'd need to look in `dba_tab_permissions` and/or `role_tab_permissions` to see what users and/ or roles have been given `execute` access on the package.

Comment: Perfect @JustinCave thank you very much for your support !! I'm going to validate that;) a good Friday greeting!

Comment: @JustinCave did me wrong, yes I have privileges :(, maybe I have to run the package before executing a query?

Comment: There is no such thing as "running a package".  A package is just a collection of procedures and functions.  Post the queries you're using that show you have access.  Are you running a raw SQL statement?  Or is the SQL statement you are executing in a PL/SQL block?

Comment: Thank you very much, finally talking with those in charge of the DB we were able to verify that it was indeed a matter of execution privileges on the packages. Thanks for your help me @JustinCave!!